# Problem Reading csv File with Special Characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am trying to read in a csv file in Python using pd.read_csv('file_name.csv') but some special characters seem to be throwing it off. In particular, some fields have single quotes, some have double quotes, and some even have multiple copies of single or double quotes right next to each other. This messes up those rows of the DataFrame completely. What I want is for the resulting DataFrame to still include these characters, not treat it as if I am trying to specify a String.

Here is a sample of the problem csv:

ID, Name, Year Published, Min Players, Max Players, Play Time, Min Age, Users Rated, Rating Average, Rank, 
231972, POWERUP, 2018, 1, 5, 120, 8, 59, 7, 84, 9483
4016, """Scratch One Flat Top!""", 1995, 2, 4, 180, 12, 50, 7, 44, 9484
261898, War For Chicken Island, 2020, 1, 4, 240, 10, 85, 7, 27, 9485

However, when I run the code

```
df.iloc[9482]
```

it yields

ID                              4016,"""Scratch One Flat Top!""",1995,2,4,180,...
Name                            9484
Year Published                  NaN
Min Players                     NaN
Max Players                     NaN
Play Time                       NaN
Min Age                         NaN
Users Rated                     NaN
Rating Average                  NaN
Rank                            NaN
Name: 9482, dtype: object

I have tried using all the quotechar and quoting options in read_csv but with no luck. Since both single and double quotes appear, quotechar='"' or quotechar="'" will not work. The closest I have gotten is to use quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE like

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

However, this causes the problem rows to have new " quotes where there were none before.

Comment: Can you show the resulting dataframe?

Comment: Agreed with Zack, a sample would be great. But also have you tried `csv.QUOTE_ALL`? it has worked for me in a few similar situations

Comment: ... a few lines of offending CSV would be helpful too.

Comment: The problem seems to be with whatever created the CSV. There are rules for how to escape quotes and delimiters in the data. If they're not followed correctly and consistently, it will be difficult to read the file properly.

Comment: you might try:
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', **encoding='utf8'**)